# Is it a red flag for a patent attorney to be a prolific inventor in diverse fields

Tags: ownership, patent-services, attorney

A patent attorney has several patents to her name in very diverse fields. Some inventions are routine utilities, while others are highly technical & domain specific. The latter makes me wonder what's the source of inspiration. Could it be abandoned patents from clients or could it be a work of interns from different fields who didn't get credit.

Comment: could you specify if they are as inventor or applicant? i believe it can be filed as applicant without any problems

Comment: @Pushpak : Inventor & applicant both for the ones I'm concerned about.

Comment: Is the patent attorney the sole inventor on those applications or are there others?

Answer (score 1):

Primarily Opinion based answer:-

Attorney or legal firm can be **applicant** for number of inventions in diversified filed. as it only right transfer i.e. rights are purchased and inventor is compensated for inventive subject matter. such transfer as via assignments, bonds etc.

Now comes to attorney or agent being **inventor** of diversified filed, Patent law as such doesnot restrict patent grant based on opinion that person has filed application in unrelated technologies. However in such case person interested can object inventor being not true inventor but evidences of not being inventor has to be produced in front of USPTO. e.g. affidavits of true inventors, declaration, misconduct of incorrect submissions etc. Keep in mind that a person can file patent in diversified field like great Thomas Edison.

I think its best to inform you that [USPTO](https://www.federalregister.gov/articles/2013/04/03/2013-07382/changes-to-representation-of-others-before-the-united-states-patent-and-trademark-office#h-30) and BAR requires some [ethics standard](https://www.federalregister.gov/articles/2013/04/03/2013-07382/changes-to-representation-of-others-before-the-united-states-patent-and-trademark-office#h-30) for registered practitioner to be follow rules. And I really doubt that practitioner as you mentioned will jeopardize his/her carrier by doing misconduct.

Inspiration:-

Invention is what being novel and not obvious, in fact almost all invention are based on prior arts (published), by definition if a person has conceived the invention he/she is inventor. I believe that it depends on proving the fact that if attorney has filed application based on arts or teachings which were not published at that time but later on resurface then attorney can be of incorrect inspiration misconduct. If filled application being published and based on that new invention is made which is novel and inventive, then I really doubt that attorney is at fault.